# Why is cellForRowAtIndexPath adding a gradientLayer sometimes?

Tags: uitableview

I have a function that looks something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// instantiate the cell

if(indexPath.row >=4 && indexPath.row <=5)
{
[CustomTableCell addGradient];
}
}
```

So basically, only rows 4 and 5 should have a gradient background.  When the tableview first loads up, rows only rows 0 to 4 are visible and don't have gradient background which is perfect.  When I scroll a little down to see rows 4 and 5, the gradient appears on them, which is great again.  but when I scroll back up to the first row, all of a sudden i see a gradient on the first row!!!  But i never asked row 0 to have a gradient!  Additionally, when i scroll down a bit, i see gradients applied to some rows and not others.  Why is this happening?

here's the addGradient function incase it's useful:

```
- (void) addGradient
{
    if([self.layer.sublayers count] >0)
    {
        if([[self.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]])
            return;
    }

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.bounds;

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, nil];

    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that iPhone/cocoa is actually re-using an existing cell in memory for cellForRowAtIndexpath to draw cells that appear on screen.  So that's why the cell still has a gradient layer I had set before.  So i updated my stylecell function to remove a layer if it exists, by using this code:

```
- (void) styleCell
{
    if([self.layer.sublayers count] >0)
    {
        if([[self.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]])
        {
            [[self.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperlayer];
//            return;
        }
    }

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.bounds;

    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, nil];


    [self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
@end
```